# Join statement in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am learning powershell, I got an example. But I am totally unable to understand it.
Here is code  :

```
if($($wordProgress -join '') -like $targetWord)
```

Comment: I don't know PS, but it sounds something like an equality check between a list joined by some delimeter `''` to a string and another string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going back to your previous question, $wordProgress is a strong-typed array.  So the `$($wordProgress -join '')` is joining the array values and comparing the joined value to $targetword.

Its in an If statement, so if it returns true, it will do whatever is in the proceeding {} block.

Here is an example of this in action.

```
[int[]]$nums = 1,2,3,4

Write-Host "Not Joined = " 
$nums

Write-Host "Joined = " 
($nums -join '')

If($($nums -join '') -like '1234'){

    Write-host "Do something!"

}
```

Also, as you are new to Powershell, I recommend you start by learning about the [Get-Help Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176848.aspx).

Here is how you would use it to learn about the -join operator

```
Get-help about_join
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing `$wordProgress` is a char-array(list of characters).

`$()` is a subexpression that is used to run something before continue processing.

`-join ''` joins the array values with a blank delimiter(so just add the values after eachother), to create a string.

`-like` matches the left side(the string created from the char-array) with the word on the right side.

This is all inside an if-test, so if the joined string matches the `$targetWord`, it would run the code that should come after your expression.

Sample:

```
PS > [char[]]$wordProgress = "a","b","c"
PS > $targetWord = 'abc'

PS > $($wordProgress -join '')
abc

PS > if($($l -join '') -like $targetWord) { "MATCH" }
MATCH
```